Bring the logo to the front of slides contents
How to keep the logo in font of text and images, I do not want the logo to be hidden by large images.
  \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Logo}
\author{Al}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[opacity=.5,inner sep=0.3cm,anchor=south east, xshift=\paperwidth]  {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-c}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{frame}
\end{document} 


It is very confusing if you just replace your code with the one from an answer.

You could abuse some other layer which is above the text layer, e.g. the footline:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[opacity=.5,inner sep=0.3cm,anchor=south east, xshift=\paperwidth]  {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-c}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{frame}
\end{document} 



I made some edits to the question, what if I want to keep the default header and footer of the theme!

@AbdelhakElfengour Then you can use \addtobeamertemplate to add stuff to the template!
